# How to load pictures in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pyscripter

I am using pygame to make a game but when I try to load my pictures it results in a `error: Couldn't open ball.png`. can any one please help? here is my entire code.

To be exact I am trying to figure out why in the `class BoxSprite` class does `("ball.png")` not load. Also why does that happen in `class missle` and `class gun` with `("arrow.png")` and `("gun.png")`???

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import KEYDOWN, KEYUP, K_SPACE, K_ESCAPE, K_RIGHT, K_LEFT

width         = 320
height        = 240
imageWidth    = 32
imageHeight   = 32

goingLeft     = True
invaderHeight = 0
gunLeft       = False
gunRight      = False
gunXpos       = (width/2)-(imageWidth/2)
delay         = 10



class BoxSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    image = None

    def __init__(self, initial_position):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        if BoxSprite.image is None:
            BoxSprite.image = pygame.image.load("ball.png")
        self.image = BoxSprite.image

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = initial_position
        self.next_update_time = 0 # update() hasn't been called yet.
       self.yPos = initial_position[1]

    def update(self, current_time, left, right):
        global goingLeft, invaderHeight, imageWidth, delay
        # Update every 2 milliseconds = 1/500th of a second.
        if self.next_update_time < current_time:
            # If we're at the left or right the screen, switch directions.
            if self.rect.topleft[0] == left:
                goingLeft = False
                invaderHeight += 1
            elif self.rect.topleft[0] == right-imageWidth:
                goingLeft = True
                invaderHeight += 1
            if goingLeft == True:
                self.rect.topleft = [self.rect.topleft[0]-1, self.rect.topleft[1]]
            else:
                self.rect.topleft = [self.rect.topleft[0]+1, self.rect.topleft[1]]
            self.rect.topleft = [self.rect.topleft[0], invaderHeight+self.yPos]
            self.next_update_time = current_time + delay

class missile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    image = None

    def __init__(self, initial_position):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        if missile.image is None:
            missile.image = pygame.image.load("arrow.png")
        self.image = missile.image

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = initial_position
        self.next_update_time = 0 # update() hasn't been called yet.

    def update(self, current_time, left, right):
        global missile
        # Update every 2 milliseconds = 1/500th of a second.
        if self.next_update_time < current_time:
            # If we're reached the top then stop
            if self.rect.topleft[1] == 0:
                missiles.remove(self)
                self.kill()
                return
            else:
                self.rect.topleft = [self.rect.topleft[0], self.rect.topleft[1]-1]
            self.next_update_time = current_time + 4

class gun(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    image   = None

    def __init__(self):
        global width, imageHeight, gunXpos
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        if gun.image is None:
            gun.image = pygame.image.load("gun.png")
        self.image = gun.image

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = [gunXpos, height-imageHeight]
        self.next_update_time = 0 # update() hasn't been called yet.

    def update(self, current_time, left, right):
        global gunXpos, width, imageWidth

        # check update
        if self.next_update_time < current_time:
            if gunLeft and gunXpos>0:
                gunXpos -= 1
            if gunRight and gunXpos<width-imageWidth:
                gunXpos += 1
            self.rect.topleft = [gunXpos, self.rect.topleft[1]]
            self.next_update_time = current_time + 1


def checkInput():
    global gunLeft, gunRight, missiles, gunXpos, height
    for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == KEYDOWN:
          if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
              sys.exit(0)
          elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
              gunLeft = False
              gunRight = True
          elif event.key == K_LEFT:
              gunLeft = True
              gunRight = False
          else:
              missiles.append(missile([gunXpos, height]))
       elif event.type == KEYUP and event.key != K_SPACE:
          gunRight = False
          gunLeft = False

def checkCollisions():
    global missiles, boxes
    if missiles != [] and boxes != []:
        for m in missiles:
            found = False
            for b in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(m, boxes, 0):
                boxes.remove(b)
                b.kill()
                found = True
        if found:
            missiles.remove(m)
            m.kill()

pygame.init()
boxes = []
missiles = []

for x in range(0, width, 32):
    for y in range(0, 96, 32):
        boxes.append(BoxSprite([x, y]))

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([320, 240])
gunControl = gun()

while boxes != []:
    screen.fill([0, 0, 0]) # blank the screen.
    time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    for b in boxes:
        b.update(time, 0, width)
        screen.blit(b.image, b.rect)

    checkInput()
    checkCollisions()

    gunControl.update(time, 0, width)
    screen.blit(gunControl.image, gunControl.rect)
    for m in missiles:
        m.update(time, 0, width)
        screen.blit(m.image, m.rect)
    pygame.display.update()
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(gunControl, boxes, 0) != []:
        pygame.time.delay(50)
        print ("loser")
        sys.exit(0)
    if len(boxes)<10:
        delay = len(boxes)

pygame.time.delay(50)
print ("winner")
```

Comment: this is what pops up as the error - error: Couldn't open ball.png

Comment: It still isn't working do you have any other ideas that might help

Comment: The exact wording of the error message is always very helpful (and technically required when posting here) what is the path to ````ball.png````? first try putting in the full path or if it's in the same directory as the python file you could try ````pygame.image.load(os.path.join('.', 'image.png'))````

Comment: the exact wording of the error is `error: Couldn't open ball.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load

you can use `pygame.image.load(os.path.join('path', 'to', 'image.png'))`

which returns a `Surface` object. You should then be able to set your sprite's `image` attribute to equal this value.

like so:

```
def __init__(self, initial_position):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("path", "to", "ball.png"))
```